# Problemas com o PhoneGap e Storage HTML5

Tags: android, apache-cordova, localstorage

Estou criando uma pequena aplicação onde eu tenho que armazenar os dados do motorista recuperados de uma API própria para o banco de dados local da aplicação. Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça, optei por usar o HTML5 Storage. A princípio não tive grandes problemas, a princípio. Quando fui fazer uma simples consulta, deu erro. Vejam meu código e respectivamente o erro:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.returnMsg       = document.getElementById('teste');
    app.btbSubmitLogin  = document.getElementById('submit_login');

    app.db = window.openDatabase("4routes","1.0","Produção",200000);
    app.db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fornecedor_motorista (id_motorista INT(11) primary key,id_fornecedor INT(11),nome VACHAR(60),email VARCHAR(255),telefone VARCHAR(20),celular VARCHAR(20), cnh VARCHAR(20), validade VARCHAR(10),usuario VARCHAR(20), senha VARCHAR(100), created_at DATETIME)");
    });

    app.btbSubmitLogin.onclick = function(){
        var login       = $('.login').val();
        var senha       = $('.senha').val();
        var teste       = $('#teste').html();
        var idMotorista = '';
        $.getJSON(
            "<Minha API", 
            function(data){
                app.db.transaction(function(tx){
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM fornecedor_motorista',[],function(tx,res){
                        console.log(res.rows.item.length);
                        console.log(res.rows.item(1));
                    });
                });
            }
        );
    }
},
```

Como podem ver, ao iniciar a aplicação já é criado o banco de dados, caso ele não exista. O segundo ponto é, ao criar as tabelas ele faz uma requisição no nosso servidor e retorna um JSON om os dados do motorista. Esses dados são retornados normalmente, porém, quando eu faço logo abaixo a consulta pra ver a tabela, obviamente, ela está vazia, mas vejam que estranho. Tem dois `console.log` como retorno da query, um pra retornar seu tamanho e o outro o objeto de dados. Este é o retorno do primeiro `console.log`:

```
08-28 16:36:02.448: I/chromium(14642): [INFO:CONSOLE(62)] "1", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (62)
```

E este é o retorno do segundo:

```
08-28 16:36:02.453: I/chromium(14642): [INFO:CONSOLE(63)] "Uncaught RangeError: Item index is out of range.", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (63)
```

Já tentei fazer inserções na tabela `fornecedor_motorista`, mas com esse problema dele não me apresentar o tamanho correto fica difícil entender o tamanho correto dos dados. Poderiam me explicar e me dar uma luz com relação a esse problema?

Agradeço desde já.

Algumas observações:

Ao tentar criar o banco de dados, eu uso uma propriedade da classe de localStorage pra verificar a existência do banco de dados e ela me retorna `null`:

```
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('dbExists'));
```

Isso me retorna:

```
08-28 17:00:57.566: I/chromium(22007): [INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "null", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (59)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obter o número de elementos retornados na consulta utilize:

```
res.rows.length
```

Ao invés de :

```
res.rows.item.length
```

Vale lembrar também que a linha a seguir está tentando acessar o elemento no índice 1, e portanto o segundo elemento da consulta:

```
res.rows.item(1)
```

Agora, Local Storage e Web SQL são coisas diferentes. Se o `getItem` retorna `null` siginifica que você não salvou nenhum valor com a chave `dbexists`, logo ele não encontra nada com essa chave. Uma alternativa é você atribuir esse valor ao criar o database:

```
app.db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fornecedor_motorista (id_motorista INT(11) primary key,id_fornecedor INT(11),nome VACHAR(60),email VARCHAR(255),telefone VARCHAR(20),celular VARCHAR(20), cnh VARCHAR(20), validade VARCHAR(10),usuario VARCHAR(20), senha VARCHAR(100), created_at DATETIME)",[],function(tx,res){
        window.localStorage.setItem("dbExists",true);
    });
});
```

Comment: é isso mesmo amigo. Obrigado.